# How does Excel convert 12 hour time (text values) into decimal numbers?

Tags: excel, datetime, type-conversion

I'm trying to find the manual function on how Excel converts am/pm time (text) values into numeric decimals (using the Format menu > Number while selecting my 12 hour time column).

For example, how does 12:30:00 PM turn into 0.52083?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Date and time can be handled in many ways. The time representation you are observing in Excel is based on `1 day = 24 hours = 1.0`. So `12:00 pm` should be exactly `0.5`, while `12:30:00 pm` would be a bit (`30/(24*60) = 1/48 = 0.0208333`) above.

Btw. 12/24 hour is just a region specific presentation issue. Internally this doesn't affect the actual date and time values.